# ASP.NET website is not resizing on mobile phone

Tags: android, html, asp.net

Good afternoon. I have a task to understand what is happening. Website was made before me.
If you try to resize the browser to 320x240 you will see that the site is adapted, and if you go through the mobile phone Android it is not. Someone can tell what's wrong? Where to start looking?
Website is using MasterPages. Almost all elements are HTML.

[LINK](https://mif.antaris.ua)
mif.antaris.ua

Comment: How exactly are you differentiating between your different-size layout? I can't find it in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you need to look in css files for `@media` tags.

it seems like the mobile css has a `max-width: 320px` or something similar.

anyway, try putting all **mobile** css inside something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
    /* mobile css */
}
```

this will apply the css code within the @media block only when screen width is lower than 400px.

hope that helps.

Comment: There is no @media tags in CSS :(

Comment: No. For example: If i cut HTML code from the Master Page and create just HTML Page then it adapts. I think it is some settings in ASP.NET, but i don't know for sure.

Comment: can you capture the whole <head> tag as well?

Comment: I have found what was wrong

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

Was missing in the GlobalMasterpage

Comment: that's what i looked for - the viewport in the head :-)